# Laravel display images from storage/app/public

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

I am trying to display images from the storage/app/public folder. Whenever my controller retrieves the images form this folder with

```
$images = Storage::files('public');
```

The files retrieved from here are prefixed with `public/`, rather than `storage/`.
The problem this causes is that an image can be found `localhost/storage/filename.jpg`, but cannot be found with `localhost/public/filename.jpg` or `localhost/storage/public/filename.jpg`.
I can resolve this issue by manually cutting off the public prefix and replacing it with storage, but this isn't a particularly graceful way of doing things.

I have run the command php artisan storage:link and rerunning it results in a `The "public/storage" directory already exists.` message.

Comment: You shouldn't have `/public/` in your URLs. `public` should be the server's DocumentRoot for your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel comes with a built-in `public` disk in the storage configuration.

To list all files in the `storage/app/public` folder **without** prefixes, use:

```php
\Storage::disk('public')->files();
```

To get the correct URL of files inside the `storage/app/public` folder, use:

```php
\Storage::disk('public')->url($file);
```

To return the array of URLs of files inside the `storage/app/public` folder, here is an example combination:

```php
array_map(function ($f) {
    return \Storage::disk('public')->url($f);
}, \Storage::disk('public')->files());
```